# How To Merge HSV Channels

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to create a program that can manipulate the value of HSV of an image, and show the complete HSV image as default before manipulate the HSV value. I use Visual C++ 2008. And this is the algorithm to show the HSV image from 3 channels: 
1. Load an image
2. Convert RGB file into HSV
3. Split HSV file into 3 channels
4. Merge the channels
5. Show the merged channels

this is my uncomplete source code (i can't show you my complete because its too long):

```
...
...
cv::Mat Citra,CitraConv,CitraHSV[3],CitraD,Citra6,CitraH,CitraH1,CitraS,CitraS1,
CitraV,CitraV1;
std::vector<cv::Mat>CitraHSV2(3);
cv::cvtColor(Citra,CitraConv,CV_BGR2HSV);
cv::split(CitraConv,CitraHSV);
CitraH=CitraHSV[0];
CitraH1=CitraH;
CitraS=CitraHSV[1];
CitraS1=CitraS;
CitraV=CitraHSV[2];
CitraV1=CitraV;
CitraHSV2[0]=CitraH1;
CitraHSV2[1]=CitraS1;
CitraHSV2[2]=CitraV1;
cv::merge(CitraHSV2,CitraD);//Error Here
Citra6=CitraD; 
pictureBoxCitra2->Image=IplImageToBitmap(&(IplImage)Citra6);
```

But, when I execute the program, I got error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException'". The error was appeared from the cv::merge function. Can anyone help me? What is the problem of this program? because there was no syntax error when i build solution (F7) the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my blog posting and source code on GitHub manipulating an image stream from the webcam which does exactly what you are asking for.

It is written in Scala, but it will be easy for you to filter out the information you need like splitting up the channels, merging them and so on. Porting it to C++ should be a no brainer.

[Color Extractor](http://ladstatt.blogspot.co.at/2013/09/color-extractor.html)